# how to create or query registry with RegOpenKeyEx

Tags: c++, c, registry

I want to write a registry value into

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\Identity  =>  key = tName , value="user1"
```

but every time I got  `"RegOpenKeyEx SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\Identity failed (error=2) "`
as error suggest the Identity key is not present in the registry.

How to create a registry if it is not present.
I want to create if the key is not present and open it registry is there.

```
lStat = RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, /*handle of open key */
        szSubKey, /* address of name of subkey to open */
        0, /* reserved */
        KEY_READ , /* security access mask */
        &hKey /* address of handle of open key */
        );   
if ( lStat != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
      sprintf(szMsg,"RegOpenKeyEx %s failed (error=%ld) ",
        szSubKey, lStat);
      traceMsg(szMsg);
      return lStat;
    }

   lStat = RegSetValueEx(hKey,(LPCTSTR)szValue, NULL, &Type, 
            (LPBYTE)szUser, strlen(szUser)+1);
```

[image]

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly what is going on. Ex: are you passing the right string? Try general debugging technique, i.e. try numerous variations, like try to open some other key, like just "Software". Will that work? if yes, try something more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Does this key exist there? MSDN:

> Unlike the RegCreateKeyEx function, the RegOpenKeyEx function does not
>   create the specified key if the key does not exist in the registry.

Try `regedit` first.

Second, you specify `KEY_READ` and then want to write something.